# batch save but not overwrite

Tags: batch-file, overwrite

I need to modify a `.bat` file from scanner which starts scanning and after save file to directory. `c:\Data\scan1.tif`

Now this script always overwrites the old file, I want to change it and save that file without overwriting in format like: scan1_1.tif, scan1_2.tif scan1_3.tif etc.

code from .bat:

```
call DirectScan.Bat -config c:\Scanner\directscan1.xml -cs1 c:\Data\scan1.tif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
set /a c=1
for /f "tokens=2 delims=._" %%a in ('dir /b "c:\Data\scan1*tif"') do set/a c=c+1

call DirectScan.Bat -config c:\Scanner\directscan1.xml -cs1 c:\Data\scan1_%c%.tif
```